# Can you store facebook users' data and for how long?

Tags: facebook, privacy

Hi
I am developing a facebook app that involves the use of the user's email and ID. Storing users’ info to database is a more efficient approach for the purpose of the app. I am wondering if I am allowed to do this. I have read that facebook does not allow the storage of any kind of user's data for more than 7 days, however officially facebook website does not seem to mention this. Do you have any information about this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official policies are [here](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/).  One relevant paragraph is:

> "You may cache data you receive
>   through use of the Facebook API in
>   order to improve your application’s
>   user experience, but you should try to
>   keep the data up to date. This
>   permission does not give you any
>   rights to such data."

Comment: I came across this part but it I was in doubt since the word cache is linked to html pages cache in my mind. I will take that as a yes. Thanks

Comment: Caching does not necessarily refer to HTTP caching, and the policy does seem to allow caching in a database.