# Facebook Api program flow

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm working out a project that is tightly connected with Facebook. However, I got several questions related to the program flow.

A user may authenticate through Facebook, allowing me to use the user's access_token for data querying. Now, when I need the data, I call the api. This happens more frequently (on different pages, with the fields required to provide the view the needed data). A disadvantage I see is that I query Facebook's API everytime a request is made on one of my website it's pages. Is this a bad thing to do?

Another option would be to store the entire data array in a session (or request it when no session is found) and pull the needed data out of it, and not just the fb id and access token.

If someone has a better idea, or has experience with this, throw it towards me. Any tips are appreciated.

Regards,
matvp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess It's better if you
Query all the data that you may need and Store it in the Session, and use the session further on with your website.
or, Query all the data you want and store it with ID in your DB whatever your DB is, and then also Query your DB whenever you need the data

Comment: I went with the database idea, loading time improved with 80%.

Comment: @MatthiasVanParijs Good to know, But there's more things that you need to know about storing User's data [here](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/)
"You may cache data you receive through use of the Facebook API in order to improve your application’s user experience, but you should try to keep the data up to date. This permission does not give you any rights to such data."

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I hold two extra fields in my db: last_local_update, fb_last_update. They are self explanatory. If they differ, I get the new user data from Facebook and push the changes through. I think I might go with an extra field to check the data source (own input or Facebook). If the data is changed by own input, it would simply ignore the changes made by Facebook. Eg; some prefer a different email address. To optimise loading speed a little further, I use memcached for obvious and redundant data (eg; languages, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is better that you store user data you may need for the entire session, a simple caching of these data let you avoid a lot of queries.

The following Stack Overflow question could help you:

[Can you store facebook users' data and for how long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704003/can-you-store-facebook-users-data-and-for-how-long)